# Close FancyBox Before AJAX Post

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, fancybox

I have following code.I show user a fancybox and they  click Submit on Form I close fancybox and show them processing on page and do an AJAX post using JQuery. But some how fancybox gets stays open until AJAX form post is completed.Which creates confusion for user .

```
   function BeginProcess(){
       $.fancybox.close();
       $("#imgProcess").attr("src", "/admin/images/loading_animation.gif");
       $('#imgProcess').show();
       PostAJAXForm();
}

function PostForm(FormData){
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process_image.jsp",
                data: FormData,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                async: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    response = $.trim(response);
                    $('#imgProcess').delay(10000).hide();
                    return response;                    
                 },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     alert("There was an error. Please undo image and perform action again. " );
                     $('#lblProcess').delay(5000).hide();
                     return;
                   }
                });
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `PostAJAXForm()` function? Also, you can chain jQuery functions together if you prefer. Example: `$("#imgProcess").attr("src", "/admin/images/loading_animation.gif").show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `$.fancybox.close()` in Jquery' Ajax's beforeSend function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

This should help you out too
http://snipplr.com/view/47979/close-a-fancybox-when-you-submit-a-form-with-ajax

Comment: @Satish That snipplr link is incorrect. That will only close fancybox after the response has been received from the server.

Comment: Agree, I think pasted a wrong link, Here's the correct one, scroll down to comment by Andrew Wirick, who points to beforeSend: http://www.readmespot.com/question/o/3569439/close-fancybox-after-action-

Comment: why it would not close if i do it before even doing ajax request ?

Comment: Strange but Still it closes only after the ajax post is complete :( .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet:

```
var params = $(this).serialize();
var self = this;

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: self.action,
            data: params,
            beforeSend: function(){
                    alert('Closing');
                    $.fancybox.close();
            },
            success: function(data){
                    alert('Finished processing form');
                    return false;
            },
            dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Sorry if something is messed up or left out from that snippet - but you should get the idea.